# Navigator.pushnamed doesn't work in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to write a page to show the elements of a music album uploaded to Firestore, but when I navigate to another page using Navigator.pushNamed, passing the album name as an argument, I get an error:

FlutterError (Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/album", Item1) in the _WidgetsAppState.

First page code:

```
    import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:soundstream/album.dart';
import 'package:soundstream/albumPage.dart';
import 'package:soundstream/songList.dart';

class StartPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<StartPage> createState() => _StartPageState();
}

class _StartPageState extends State<StartPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(height: 32.0),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'Hi!',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 24.0),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 32.0),
                Text(
                  'Items',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 38.0),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                AlbumList((album) => {
                      Navigator
                          .pushNamed(context, '/album', arguments: album)
                    }),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Second page code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:soundstream/songList.dart';

class AlbumPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final album;
  final Function callback;

  AlbumPage(this.album, this.callback);

  @override
  _AlbumPageState createState() => _AlbumPageState();
}

class _AlbumPageState extends State<AlbumPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 50, 0, 0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text(
                widget.album,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 38.0),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 16.0),
              Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 0, 0, 15),
                  child: 
                  Text(
                  'Tracklist',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 38.0),
                )
                ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

How can i fix it? I would really appreciate an explanation!

Comment: Have you added ```/album``` route in your route generator file with album as argument ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you you register you the page that you want to navigate to in the material app routes https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation#using-named-routes